# Java: "Listening" to a DataStream

Tags: java, networking, stream

I have a program that connects to a server, and sends/receives data through an input and output data stream. 
I want to debug it and see if the messages that are being passed are correct, so I have to read whats being sent over the streams, but the connection has a 1 second timeout. (on the server side, and I cant control that) 
Is there a way to listen to the stream so I can get the data from it to the console AND have the data still be sent?

```
public void foo(DataInputStream in, DataOutputStream out){
    //Some code to make the console write whatever is sent in the out stream
    //And received in the in stream. 

    out.writeUTF("SOME TEXT");
    String s = in.readUTF();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Jakarta Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) will help you. Where you create your `DataInputStream`, insert a `TeeInputStream` that writes to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. You can then examine that byte array at your leisure.

Comment: Drats! Beat me to it :). Got to second this: TeeInputStream is the way, the truth and the light for tasks like this.

Comment: unfortunately I have to use DataInputStream (and output) class, so I can't use anything that doesn't extends that.

Comment: @Benny - `TeeInputStream` is a decorator: wherever you create your `DataInputStream`, you would still do so. However, as part of the construction chain you would insert `TeeInputStream`.

Comment: oh so I create a Tee stream from the original stream, and send that to the DataInputStream, correct?

Comment: @Benny - yes. At the same time, if you're not already using a `BufferedInputStream` (part of the JDK), you should add one of those into your stack.